# LEN() of % in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Example Data:

**Sample #1**

```
<br/>Out at Jan 01, 2019, 5:27 pm <small>by Shyam</small>
<br/>In at Jan 02, 2019, 2:06 pm <small>by Ram</small>
```

**Sample #2**

```
<br/>Out at Jan 01, 2019, 01:22 pm <small>by Ram</small>
<br/>In at Jan 02, 2019, 2:22 pm <small>by Shyam</small>
```

I need query to return just the **Sample #2** as I'm looking for data by `Ram` at `Jan 01, 2019`.

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `log` LIKE '%Jan 01, 2019 % Ram %';
```

That query is returning both **Sample #1** and **Sample #2** as the length of `%` after `date` is not defined.

I need to figure-out a way to give `%` character length

Like:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `log` LIKE '%Jan 01, 2019 LEN(%)=3 Ram %';
```

I tried to achieve the required fields with other queries but all failed. Is there anyway to count string length of `%`?

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression.  Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl`
WHERE `log` REGEXP 'Jan 01, 2019 .{3} Ram ';
```

The `.` represents any character.  The `{3}` says it can be repeated up to three times.

I'm not sure where the "3" comes from.  It seems like there are about 10 characters.  You can put a range in like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl`
WHERE `log` REGEXP 'Jan 01, 2019 .{1,15} Ram ';
```

Comment: Is `regexp` valid in version of MySQL below 8.0 ?

Comment: It returned empty result. May be because there are characters before `Jan` and after `Ram`? I used to denote it with `%`

Comment: @MichałTurczyn . . . Yes.  It has been part of MySQL since basically forever, I think (I mean all the 5+ versions).

Comment: @LIGHT . . . No.  A regular expression is not anchored to the beginning of the string.  It matches anywhere in the string.  The issue is probably the number of intervening characters -- it is also possible that `.` does not match newlines if they are in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_` wildcard representing any characters. Text between date and `by Ram` is `5:27 pm <small>`, so you can use `_______________` (exactly 15 characters), so pattern could be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl`
WHERE `log` LIKE '%Jan 01, 2019 __________by Ram %'
OR `log` LIKE '%Jan 01, 2019 ___________by Ram %'; -- if the times is 12:12 for example
```

Since this is log column (I assume) it's structured nicely and the numbers of characetrs assumed won't vary due to some typos, etc.

Comment: Problem is, we don't have exact number of `_` because the time can sometimes be `2:22` or `12:22`

Comment: @LIGHT Then use `or` with one `_` less :)

Comment: That certainly did work for me and I upvoted your answer. But I think i'll go with `REGEXP` as right answer for community's sake. Thank you @Michal

Answer (score 0):

You can use an underscore as placeholder for one character. Repeat them to match several characters. Or just use HTML:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `log` LIKE '%Jan 01, 2019 <small>by Ram</small>';
```